# how to start and stop activity indicator while json data are fetching in swift 2?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift2, indicator

here is my function for getting data

```
let urlstring = "example.com"
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let url = NSURL(string: urlstring)

        session.dataTaskWithURL(url!) { (data: NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if let responseData = data
            {

                //  var names = [String]()
                do {
                    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: .AllowFragments)

                    if let job = json["response"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                        if job.count == 0{
                            print("error")
                        }
                        for jobs in job {
                            if let id = jobs["id"] as? String, let ccode = jobs["city_code"] as? String, let cname = jobs["city_name"] as? String, let cparent = jobs["city_parent"] as? String{
                                if check_city_exist(id){
                                    insert_cities(id, city_code: ccode, city_name: cname, city_parent: cparent)
                                }
                                else{
                                    update_cities(id, city_code: ccode, city_name: cname, city_parent: cparent)
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                } catch {
                    print("error serializing JSON: \(error)")
                }

            }


            }.resume()
```

and my code in viewDidLoad for indicator showing and stoping

```
 prog.startAnimating() // prog is my activity indicator
let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue) { () -> Void in
        load_data()
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.prog.stopAnimating()
        })
    }
```

when view is loading, indicator starts and immediately stops before loading data done, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `loadData` is another asynchronous task, so code execution moves on to the next line - and immediately stops your indicator!

You have to move the stop call to inside your data load closure - after you have finished processing the `jobs` loop - and make sure to include `dispatch_get_main_queue` for all UI calls

Comment: Happy to help - if the answer is useful, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

PLEASE IMPLEMENT i hope it's work !!!

```
    let urlstring = "example.com"
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let url = NSURL(string: urlstring)

    prog.startAnimating() // Here Start Animating 

    session.dataTaskWithURL(url!) { (data: NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        self.prog.stopAnimating() // here we stop animating because response is either success or failure

        if let responseData = data
        {
           //Here do with response
        }


        }.resume()
    }
```